# Are there compilers that implement immunity-aware programming techniques?

Tags: compiler, optimization

Are there compilers with flags or directives to implement [immunity-aware programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immunity-aware_programming) techniques such as

- function token passing
- data integrity verification and/or correction
- function parameter duplication
- test duplication
- branching duplication
- instruction duplication

to harden software against electrical transients? Ideally, it would be freely available, but I'd also like to know about familiarity or experiences with proprietary toolchains for automating the use of such techniques. Also, I'd appreciate comments or community edits naming additional software-based prophylactics in this vein.